# Get groups that are exactly equal to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ansi-sql

I have a query that groups easily. I need to get the groups that have exactly the same records to another table (relationship).

I'm using ANSI-SQL under SQL Server, but I accept an answer of any implementation.

For example:

Table1:

```
Id | Value
---+------
1  |  1
1  |  2
1  |  3
2  |  4
3  |  2
4  |  3
```

Table2:

```
Value | ...
------+------
  1   | ...
  2   | ...
  3   | ...
```

In my example, the result is:

```
Id |
---+
1  |
```

How imagined that it could be the code:

```
SELECT Table1.Id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Id
HAVING ...? -- The group that has exactly the same elements of Table2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
select t1.Id
from Table2 t2
join Table1 t1 on t1.value = t2.value
group by t1.Id
having count(distinct t1.value) = (select count(*) from Table2)
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03045/5)

Comment: Brilliant solution! It is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To get the same sets use an inner join:

```
SELECT Table1.Id
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
GROUP BY Table1.Id
HAVING ...? --
```

Comment: Using INNER JOIN Table1 may contain elements that are not in Table2. I need the group of Table1 to be exactly like to Table2.

Comment: INNER JOIN will only give the overlap. LEFT JOIN will give you elements in T1 which are not in T2.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE #T1 (ID INT , [Values] INT) INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,6)

CREATE TABLE #T2 ([Values] INT) INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)

SELECT * FROM #T1

SELECT * FROM #T2

SELECT A.ID
FROM 
(   SELECT ID , COUNT(DISTINCT [Values]) AS Count FROM #T1
    GROUP BY ID
) A

JOIN 
(
    SELECT T1.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT T2.[Values])  Count
    FROM #T1 T1
    JOIN #t2 T2
        ON T1.[Values] = T2.[Values]
    GROUP BY T1.ID
) B
    ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Count = B.Count